# PHP input text with variables

Tags: php, html, escaping

Consider the following code for printing questions from text file:

```
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        if($line_num%3 == 1){
            echo 'Question '.$count.':'.'<br/>'.'<input type="text" value="$line" class="tcs"/>'.'<br/>';
```

I've tried many string escaping combinations. The problem is that I get `$line` **inside the text field** instead of the variable value. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using PHP first time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the variable from the `'` quoted string, or use `"` so the variable is interpreted.

```
echo 'Question ' . $count . ':<br/><input type="text" value="' . $line . '" class="tcs"/><br/>';
```

or

```
echo "Question " . $count . ":<br/><input type=\"text\" value=\"$line\" class=\"tcs\"/><br/>";
```

The first option is better, since you don't have to escape anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
echo 'Question ' . $count . ':'.'<br/>'.'<input type="text" value="' . $line . '" class="tcs"/>'.'<br/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables don't get processed in single quoted strings. You need to use double quotes or another way of inserting them (such as concatenation).